# Is it possible to run Microsoft Orleans in classic ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: orleans

Is it possible to run Microsoft Orleans in the classic ASP.NET MVC framework (.net 4.8)?
I am trying to search it all over the internet, but all links and docs point to asp.net core version.

If someone could point me in the right direction I would be grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://dotnet.github.io/orleans/docs/index.html (version 3.4.3 at time of this answer)

> Orleans is compatible with .NET Standard 2.0 and above, running on Windows, Linux, and macOS, in full .NET Framework or .NET Core.

and

> ### Run Anywhere
>
> Orleans runs anywhere that .NET Core or .NET Framework are supported. This includes hosting on Linux, Windows, and macOS and deploying to Kubernetes, virtual or physical machines, on premises or in the cloud, and PaaS services such as Azure Cloud Services.

So I guess yes